# Get counter from iterator mediator WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any way to get how many time WSO2 ESB iterator mediator iterated, in terms of some counter value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is as many iteration as xml fragments given by the xpath expression you've defined inside iterate mediator and you can use xpath function "count" to find this value, exemple :

message :

```
<root>
  <value>
    ...
  </value>
  <value>
    ...
  </value>
</root>
```

Mediation :

```
<iterate expression="//value">
   <target>
     ...
   </target>
</iterate>
```

XPATH giving the number of iteration : `count(//value)`

Internally, a property "messageSequence" or "messageSequence.ID" (where ID is the value of the iterate mediator's optional id attribute) is initialized with such a counter (it give you something like 0/2 and 1/2 with my sample) but I'm not sure you should use that...

Comment: Thanks Jean. I have an iterator which is calling another sequence under target. Can you please advise where to add XPATH as count ?             `<iterate expression="$body/ComplexData/ComplexData">
            <target sequence="LogDataSeq"/>
         </iterate>`

Comment: You must define a property before iterate : <property name="MY_COUNTER" expression="count(//value)"/>. I've updated my answer with other informations...